# Aspect ratio of map in arc gis

Tags: arcgis

I have two maps drawn in same layout (arch A Landscape) and same scale (1:1000000) in arc gis 10.4.1. But two maps look different in terms of height and width. Is there any settings to adjust this?

The map is region 2 of TN (Chattanooga area).

[image: map1]

[image: map2]

Comment: What is the projection of each data source? Were they made from the same MXD?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to source data being in different projections, which can look like an "aspect ratio" problem. [Project all your data](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) into the same projection and all your maps will have the same perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. In my case, I went to "Data Frame Properties" -> Data Frame, in the Extent tab select Automatic in the list box. Hope this helps!